# Magento 2 : How to Apply Custom Discount from Controller?

Tags: magento2, discount

How can i apply **Custom Discount** to cart using my custom controller ??

I've read many answers on web but all are same, All uses Model,**CustomDiscount.php** file to apply discount.

I would like to apply it from my custom controller OR Programmatically ?

Any help would be really **APPRECIATE**.

Comment: Have you found any solution?